Can the hemoglobin be fed something besides iron to make blood a different color?
A bit of context here. A species of Fairies in my world have silver-colored blood, and while researching for that, I learned that hemoglobins essentially require blood to be red because they need iron to form. Is there anything else that could theoretically replace iron's role in the (human) bloodstream, or something that could be added alongside to change the color despite the iron? I mostly want to know so I can get realistic bloodstain colors and see if there would be any side effects

There's: Is it possible for an intelligent species to have non-red blood?, or Would it be possible for my fantasy creature to have black blood? or the most comprehensive one Other blood colors which explores a whole range of alternatives. Worth using the search bar up top.

You specifically ask about changing the hemoglobin, but there's no particular reason the color of the blood has to be determined by the oxygen-carrying component of the blood...the red color (or other color from a different oxygen carrier) could be obscured by other pigments with different functions. Another thought...you mention blood stains, but those aren't bright red like fresh blood. Could the silver be something that happens on exposure to air or as it clots on a wound? Maybe it produces a silvery protective layer while it forms a scab, instead of the blood actually being silver?
